# renaming file in bash from an info file

Tags: bash, rename

I have a directory under which I have 4 files

```
ERR315336_1.fastq.gz  ERR315336_2.fastq.gz  ERR315337_1.fastq.gz  ERR315337_2.fastq.gz
```

Also I have the info file for these 4 files in a sep file named info.txt

```
placenta_6c      placenta_6c_ERR315336_1.fastq.gz    ERR315336_1.fastq.gz
placenta_6c      placenta_6c_ERR315336_2.fastq.gz    ERR315336_2.fastq.gz
thyroid_5b   thyroid_5b_ERR315337_1.fastq.gz     ERR315337_1.fastq.gz
thyroid_5b   thyroid_5b_ERR315337_2.fastq.gz     ERR315337_2.fastq.gz
```

I want to change the name of my files in the directory from the info.txt file so after changing names my directory should look like this:

```
 placenta_6c_ERR315336_1.fastq.gz 
 placenta_6c_ERR315336_2.fastq.gz 
 thyroid_5b_ERR315337_1.fastq.gz 
 thyroid_5b_ERR315337_2.fastq.gz
```

So basically changing `ERR315336_1.fastq.gz to placenta_6c_ERR315336_1.fastq.gz` 
and so on. I have a huge info list file. How can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk-ishly:

```
cd directory-with-files
awk '{system("echo mv " $3 " " $2)}' < /path/to/info.txt
```

bash-edly:

```
cd directory-with-files
while read -r junk new old
do
  echo mv "$old" "$new"
done < /path/to/info.txt
```

Remove the echo's when it looks good.

This does not do any error-checking for spaces in the filenames, or quote-marks in the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ while read -r c1 c2 c3; do echo mv "$c3" "$c2"; done < info.txt
mv ERR315336_1.fastq.gz placenta_6c_ERR315336_1.fastq.gz
mv ERR315336_2.fastq.gz placenta_6c_ERR315336_2.fastq.gz
mv ERR315337_1.fastq.gz thyroid_5b_ERR315337_1.fastq.gz
mv ERR315337_2.fastq.gz thyroid_5b_ERR315337_2.fastq.gz
```

- Read the `info.txt` file line by line and save the 3 fields (assumes space/tab separation)
- `echo` is for dry run, remove once it is okay
- Further reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: One query: Why using quotes around $c3 and $c2?? I was stuck at this step and I didn't use quotes and it was giving me so destination operand error

Comment: using quotes avoids possible mangling of filenames due to shell interpretation.. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767 but for given sample it shouldn't matter